# intellij idea specify repository for downloading sources

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

It seems that question can be related to [How to automatically attach source code for dependency in Intellij?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295040/how-to-automatically-attach-source-code-for-dependency-in-intellij) but it`s not in full manner.

In debug mode I'm getting into decompiled file and idea ask me to download or set the path to sources.

[image: Download button]

For resolving I'm using some nexus repository which aggregates different vendors public jars (proxy repositories,reuploaded jars and etc). Unfortunately it contains jars but very often it doesn't contain sources or javadocs.

But at the same time vendors' repositories contain sources. After clicking "download" button - I can see that idea try to find sources only in "oss.sonatype.org" repository.

[image: Downloading sources]

So is any ability to set the list of repositories where Idea can search sources?

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ will respect your normal Maven configuration. You can define repositories in the actual pom.xml or in your maven user setting under `~/.m2/settings.xml`. See https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html

Answer (score 0):

Check settings of IntelliJ IDEA "Settings-->Maven-->Repositories

There are two sections:

- Index Maven Repositories
- Artifactory or Nexus Service URLs

Comment: I tried, these settings contains repos for maven integration used by Idea. I have added some set of maven public repositories which definitely contains required sources. Even after idea restart download button still tries to connect only to oss.sonatype.org (Also by default there was two other repositories) and fails with source finding. Thank you.